# Theming the Timeline Area outside the Playback/Rendering Range

Tags: customization, theme, timeline

The Timeline Area’s background color seems to be controlled by Theme Space Settings > Window Background — but the background *outside* the playback/rendering range always seems to be a darker version of this color. Here, I’ve set all the Timeline colors I can find to fully opaque #ff0000, but the out-of-range background is still darker:

[image: notice the darker red out-of-range]
[image: all colors set to red]

Is there a way to directly control the out-of-range background color? If out-of-range is actually partially transparent, is there a way to change the backstop color (eg. so that the out-of-range background appears lighter)?

Comment: Probably hardcoded to always be `* 2` darker than the current color no doubt to be able to distinguish the active set length from the rest.

Comment: Off-topic of course, but what a bright theme. I'd say flamingly bright.

Comment: I don't need no rose-tinted glasses, I tell ya that…